# Can i set relative path to java.security.auth.login.config?

Tags: java, spring, jaas, java-security

In my Spring Boot app i need to call to:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", authConf);
```

where authConf seems to be expected as an absolute path to the file.

the problem is, my Spring Boot app is packaged and executed as a jar and i want to package the file inside the jar.

The answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422406/where-to-place-security-configuration-file-in-war) might work only when a WAR is deployed in a server. It doesn't seem to work when we run JARs with embedded container.

***is there way i could set a relative path to java.security.auth.login.config to refer to my conf file packaged within my jar ?***

Answer (score 0):

I know that the answer is about 6 years too late, but I recently faced the same issue and found and answer. Maybe my answer will at least help the next dev who will face this issue.
 I was able to solve it is by first creating a `javax.security.auth.login.Configuration` of type `JavaLoginConfig` and then use the `Configuration.setConfiguration(configuration method)` of the same Configuration class. Using this method I was able to bundle our `jaas.conf` inside the jar and use a relative path to it.

To give a concrete example:

1. Get the URL of the security configuration file you want to use
   `URL configLocation=YourClass.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/jaas.conf);"`
2. Create the JavaLoginConfig configuration
   `Configuration secConfig=Configuration.getInstance("JavaLoginConf", new URIParameter(configLocation.toURI());`
3. Set the configuration to the one you created in step 2
   `Configuration.setConfiguration(secConfig);`